# C-program for finding prime factors, compilation is not stopping

Tags: c, prime-factoring

My Program to calculate the largest prime factor of 600851475143, is stuck and never stops during compilation and execution. Does anyone know why it does not finish execution?

```
#include <stdio.h> //Edited the #includes(typo) to #include 
 int main (void)
{

    long long int num = 600851475143 ;
    long long int factorCount;
    long long int bigFactor;

    for ( long long int i=1 ; i <= num; i+=2 )// Iterating through all numbers from 2, smaller than or equal to num
    {
        if ( num % i == 0) // If the number "i" is a factor of num i.e. If "i" perfectly divides num
        {
            factorCount = 0;
            //checking whether a factor "i" , is a prime factor of num
            for ( long long int j=2; j <= i ; j++  ) // Iterating through all numbers from 2, smaller than or equal to "i"
            {
                if ( i % j == 0) // If the number "j" prefectly divides or is a factor of "i"
                {
                    factorCount++; //Add 1 to factorCount
                };
            };

            if ( factorCount == 1 ) // If factorCount has not exceeded 1 i.e., the number "i" is a prime number
            {
                bigFactor = i;
            };
        };

    };
    printf("The largets prime factor of %lli is %lli\n",num,bigFactor );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _never stops during compilation and execution_ - these are two very different things. If it never stops during compilation, you never even reach execution. As to never stopping during execution... you've asked for a LOT of loops. _Never_ is a very long time, and you have not waited long enough to determine that it will _never_ stop. Your method of determining if a number is prime is not a reasonable one for that reason.

Comment: Does it even compile? #includes?

Comment: As you may know, 600851475143 is prime, so this program is going to run for a long time.  (One of the first shortcuts to take when doing brute-force factoring is to try candidate factors only up to the square root of the number you're factoring.  So you could get away with "only" 387573 loops, instead of 300425737571.)

Comment: It looks like your program mostly works, but it has a bug: it will print the wrong answer for numbers like 4 and 16 that are powers of 2.

Comment: You might also consider using a prime number sieve to generate candidate prime factors (and therefore to avoid *post hoc* primality testing).  You could integrate this with factorization.  Limiting the maximum factor tested to the square root of your target will make this more feasible.

Comment: You should also consider dividing out the maximum possible power of each prime factor you discover.  You need only test the quotient for larger prime factors.  That will sometimes help you stop the search sooner, and it saves you extra recordkeeping for the largest factor (whatever is left of `num` at the end is the largest prime factor, or else the last prime you discovered if `num` is reduced to 1).

Comment: Google, "algorithms for finding prime factors".

Comment: "why it does not finish execution?" --> Perhaps `OP's patience < program execution time`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understood your question .. so you just want to get the biggest prime factor for a certain number? If this is the case, then just do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER 600851475143

int main (void)
{
    long long int num = NUMBER;
    long long int factor;

    for (factor=2 ; num != 1; factor++) {
        if (num % factor == 0) {
            num = num / factor;
            factor = factor-1;
        }
    }
    printf("The largets prime factor of %lli is %lli\n",NUMBER, factor);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this works: the first prime factor you find is the smallest prime factor of the number; the last prime factor is the biggest. Therefore once you have found a prime factor p, there does not exist a prime factor smaller than p, because otherwise you would have found that smaller prime factor before. Hence your next prime factor is greater equals p.

Comment: `The largets prime factor of 600851475143 is 6857`

71 * 839 * 1471 * 6857 = 600851475143

Answer (score 1):

It finishes its execution, it just takes a lot of time.
You are performing a loop 600851475143 / 2 times or about 300 billion times. If the main loop takes 1ms to executes (but it should take more since there is another inner loop) then it means that time required would be about 9.5 years.

Just be patient and your loop will finish.

Comment: "Just be patient and your loop will finish" -- LOL.

Comment: Just be patient and your loop will finish with a sometimes wrong result.

Comment: ... don't worry though, you'll never see if it gives you the correct answer or not. Unless you are really really really patient... and maybe a vampire... with nothing to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
 int main (void)
{

    long long int num = 600851475143 ;
    long long int factorCount;
    long long int bigFactor;
    for ( long long int i=1 ; i <= sqrt(num); i+=2 )// Iterating through all numbers from 2, smaller than or equal to num
    {
        if ( num % i == 0) // If the number "i" is a factor of num i.e. If "i" perfectly divides num
        {
            factorCount = 0;
            //checking whether a factor "i" , is a prime factor of num
            for ( long long int j=2; j <= i ; j++  ) // Iterating through all numbers from 2, smaller than or equal to "i"
            {
                if ( i % j == 0) // If the number "j" prefectly divides or is a factor of "i"
                {
                    factorCount++; //Add 1 to factorCount
                };
            };

            if ( factorCount == 1 ) // If factorCount has not exceeded 1 i.e., the number "i" is a prime number
            {
                bigFactor = i;
            };
        };

    };
    printf("The largets prime factor of %lli is %lli\n",num,bigFactor );

    return 0;
}
```

Only calcule the root of 600851475143.

Comment: Stopping at `sqrt(num)` is a good improvement, but it makes the program print a wrong answer (er, an even more wrong answer) for prime numbers.

Comment: I know, but with the number he needs it's ok.
I would like to help more but i'm working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my best guess would be that it runs perfectly fine but takes too much time.
So what you have to do is optimize your algorithm. 
Here are some hints for improving your algorithm:

- You just need to iterate until the square root of a number to know whether or not it is a prime.
- As you have done in our outer loop (but not in your inner loop), you just have to iterate through odd numbers.
- Since you are looking for the highest prime factor, try beginning from the end and once you have reached a prime factor, stop looking.

I think that this should run in a reasonable amount of time.

EDIT: Actually, after reflexion the third point is not that obvious. Of course, it is better than going through all factors but the computation is way slower for large factors ...

Answer (score 0):

Good Afternoon 24,

The runtime of this code will take very long, very very long. But it should work, only real error is the 's' in

```
#includes <stdio.h>
```

so just be patient, you're dealing with very large numbers, iterating through odd numbers has made it much less lengthy than it could be, don

Note: If you are using an online IDE such as cpp.sh or other source, the website will most likely time out. Please use a locally installed IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This is reasonably efficient:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMBER 600851475143

static unsigned long long int gpf(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long d, q;

    while (n > 2 && !(n & 1))
        n >>= 1;

    d = 3;
    while (d * d <= n) {
        q = n / d;
        if (q * d == n)
            n = q;
        else
            d += 2;
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("The largest prime factor of %llu is %llu\n",
           NUMBER, gpf(NUMBER));
    return 0;
}
```